# How to resolve ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery'?

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, uwsgi, django-celery

Getting following error after using command `sudo uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/tagstore.conf` to start server.

```
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/tagstore/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/tagstore/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/tagstore/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/tagstore/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/tagstore/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/tagstore/tagstore/tagstore/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "/home/ubuntu/apps/tagstore/tagstore/tagstore/celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
  File "./celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 2574)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 2576, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 2577, cores: 1)
```

My celery.py file is :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tagstore.settings')

from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('tagstore')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app.conf.update(CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

I've pip installed django-celery in virtualenv folder. Please help me resolve the issue, if any other information is required please let me know.

Comment: by calling your file `celery.py` you are shadowing the built in module.

Comment: Even though this was marked as a duplicate, there is a subtle difference to your question and the one you were referred to. If you're working in your virtual environment,  don't sudo your commands. `sudo` will call packages from your OS, not the venv. So, either follow the solution that you were referred to, or don't invoke sudo privileges.